# std::multimap<std::chrono::milliseconds, T>::rbegin points to end() in MSVS-13?

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap, c++-chrono

I'm having a peculiar problem that has my team concerned about using std::chrono.

We are working with MSVS-13, so C++11.

I have a collection of object states stored in a multimap, keyed by std:chrono::milliseconds.  I want to find the last time (largest duration key value) in the map.  The obvious answer is to use rbegin():

```
class ObjectState{};
typedef std::multimap<std::chrono::milliseconds, ObjectState> MapType
main()
{
    MapType stateMap;

    // add some states

    // read the last time
    std::chrono::milliseconds lastTime = stateMap.rbegin()->first;
}
```

But in my build, this cores.  Looking at the debugger, it appears that rbegin() is pointing to an invalid location after the map, just like end() should.

And I confirmed that incrementing the iterator returned by rbegin() does indeed reach the last item in the map.

Everything I read says it ought not behave that way, and if I key the map by "double" instead of by "std::chrono::milliseconds" then rbegin()->first gives the largest time as I'd expect.

Is there some reason for std::chrono and std::multimap to be incompatible?

Comment: It is likely you have a bug in your code. Since you didn't show the code, I can't say where. Although there is a slight chance of MSVC being at fault here, I very inclined to think it is your code.

Comment: Please make a minimal example that actually fills the map. Make sure you test that (to verify it has the same behavior as you claim) before you post. This will allow us to test the bug. [mcve] I have Visual Studio 2013 so I  can test if there was code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I also wonder who upvoted this very low quality question.

Comment: There is no special interaction or incompatibility between `std::chrono::millisecond`s and `std::multimap`. Please share a [MCVE], there's no way to tell what your problem actually is from this code sample.

Comment: In c++ `main` is required to have the return type `int`. It looks like you gave it the return type `MapType`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in latest MSVC preview using simple map construction with a few `stateMap.insert({std::chrono::milliseconds(...), ObjectState{}});`.

Comment: It would be a reasonable and interesting question if the code was complete. Since it is not complete it is unanswerable.

Comment: Ok, so there's large agreement that it ought not do this. The context is a large program on a different network, so I'll try to reproduce the behavior in a little test main I can bring here. I'll be back.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::chrono::milliseconds lastTime = stateMap.rbegin()->first;
```

this results in undefined behavior if:

1. `stateMap` is empty
2. Someone has modified data inside `stateMap` that changes its order.
3. Anyone anywhere in the program has executed or will execute undefined behavior before or after this line of code.

Otherwise, it returns the largest key value stored in `stateMap`.

Comment: ... or user "[overrode](https://wandbox.org/permlink/a9HkLVmJB8E5lvF2)" default comparison (using the fact that non-templated functions take precedence in overload resolution) and provided one that doesn't conform related requirements (strict weak ordering, etc). Just nit-picking :-) **Edit:** on the second thought this one probably falls under case #3